# tuple variable in r regression model

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to use Time of the Day as an independent variable in my model. As time is a circular variable, I'm transforming it to (sin(pi * hour / 12), cos(pi * hour / 12)).

I googled around and I still don't know how to create a column in R with the (sin, cos) formatted vector/tuple values. I don't know if the models lm, glm, glm.nb (MASS) and glmer (lme4) can support this kind of data.

Excuse me for being a novice here. If vector-type variable should not be included in a regression model, I'll go to Cross Validated (stats) for suggestion on dealing with circular variables. Please help and share your experience, thanks!

Comment: Can you describe in math terms what you're after? This sounds like a programming question so CV may be off-topic?

Comment: I think you would include both components as separate predictors in your model, fit, predict, and back transform to time.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for your help! You're right that this is mainly a programming/software question, so I decided to ask here on SO. I want to know if R supports tuple values in cells of a dataframe, and, if I can create one column from 2 other columns, for example. Furthermore, if regression packages accept this kind of data. The study design is a context of my question.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Thanks for your help! Your suggestion here on SO 'cross validated' the answers I read on CV: sin and cos entered the regression model as separate variables. Unfortunately the answers I saw didn't mention how to interpret the results with the 2 variables together. I haven't got a chance to read the mentioned book Circular Statistics in R either...

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question.

Internally, R uses matrices to fit models to data. Instead of thinking about your model as a functions of tuples, you need to generate a block matrix; this is how splines are implemented, for example.

In your example, one column contains `sin(x)` and the other `cox(x)`, and the blocks is tagged with a class attribute; the functions that manage this object internally are `makepredictcall` and `predict`.

Any models using the standard model.frame / model.matrix processing should be compatible with this.

```r
sincos <- function(x, period=168/2/pi) {
  structure(cbind(`_sin`=sin(x/period), 
                  `_cos`=cos(x/period)),
            class="sincos", 
            period=period)
}
```

Here we set the class and period as attributes.

```r
makepredictcall.sincos <- function(var, call){
  if (as.character(call)[1L] != "sincos")
    return(call)
  call["period"] <- attr(var, "period")
  call
}
```

Set the period as needed on the call.

```r
predict.sincos <- function(object, newx, ...)
{
  if(missing(newx))
    return(object)
  sincos(newx, period=attr(object, "period"))
}
```

Invoke our function using the period from the fit model.

Here is a short example using `lm`:

```r
#FAKE DATA EXAMPLE
N <- 1000
hr <- sample(168, N, replace = TRUE)
Y = 5 + sinpi(hr * 2/168) + cospi(hr * 2/168) + rnorm(N)

lm(Y~sinpi(hr*2/168)+cospi(hr*2/168))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Y ~ sinpi(hr * 2/168) + cospi(hr * 2/168))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>       (Intercept)  sinpi(hr * 2/168)  cospi(hr * 2/168)  
#>            5.0078             1.0243             0.9637
```

Our custom function matches exactly:

```r
lm(Y~sincos(hr))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Y ~ sincos(hr))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>    (Intercept)  sincos(hr)_sin  sincos(hr)_cos  
#>         5.0078          1.0243          0.9637
```

Other functions will also be able to tell that the two columns are a single term in the model:

```r
anova(lm(Y~sincos(hr)))
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 
#> Response: Y
#>             Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
#> sincos(hr)   2 1051.05  525.53  553.24 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> Residuals  997  947.06    0.95                      
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

I'll add this to the `stackoverflow` package in the next few days, should anyone else find this helpful.